# How to convert an array of integer digits into an integer value?

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer, keypad

I have a keypad that I use to enter digits into a microcontroller (atmega32 avr). The user will be able to enter 1, 2 or 3 digits, because I defined the input range will be [0-999]. Each of those digits will be stored in a position of an array of integers.

So, if my array is defined as `int d[3]` and the user enters, in sequence, 2, 6, 9, I'll have `d[0] == 2`, `d[1] == 6` and `d[2] == 9`. Now I want to make an integer from those digits `{2, 6, 9}`: `value == 269`. How can I do that?

Comment: C is not C++. Please choose the appropriate tag for the code you are writing and [edit] your Q. Also format it using markdown.

Comment: Thanks. Because number can be between 0-999 it doesnt work for all. If operator enter 3 and 8 only. Then we have y=380 not 38 by this way. Am i right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer should be applicable for any language. This would be fairly simple, I would advise you to format the values in your array a little differently. I think it would be easier if the operator enters a single-digit number store it like so: `{0, 0, 5}`. If it was a double-digit number store it like so: `{0, 5, 9}`. Finally, if the operator enters a three-digit number store it like so: `{5, 9, 2}`.

Finally after you format the array you can use the following logic to get the number. For example if the array is `arr = {5, 9, 8};` then you could do the following to get it as a number:

`arr[0] * 100 + arr[1] * 10 + arr[2]`

That would work if you follow the formatting advice I gave above.

Comment: Thanks dear. You mean operator enter 0  0  5  instead if 5???  I know it makes problem easy but this is why boss eployee me only and i couldnt say i cant do that lets enter 3 digits.

Comment: You could do that, but for a better user experience, you will want the user to enter just 5, and then in your code pad it with zeroes when entering it into the array

Comment: Does that make sense Aashkanpasha?

Comment: I think my error is another where.   Keypad () scans my keypad.....t=keypad(); ...... so when i want to l[i]=t is wrong      I want to make a aray by my int numbers t. What should i do?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the exact methods and such so you'll have to consult the documentation of what you are using. You can also ask another question regarding this. If I answered your original question about how to make an integer number from array elements please approve the answer. Hope this helps and sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: @Aashkanpasha, please provide code about Keypad() or start a new question. We can't help you if you don't show any code

Comment: @AbhinavVemulapalli answers your question. Your error is a little specific. Please elaborate

Comment: @Aashkanpasha: the basic algorithm if you want to write a loop is `total = total*10 + digit`.  Then you can stop at the first non-digit.  If you have an array of `int` already, you can't tell the difference between `1` and `100` unless you use some sentinel value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the number iteratively by multiplying the digit with its corresponding unit's power.

Example: {2, 6, 9} can be expressed as ((2 * 10^2) + (6 * 10^1) + (9 * 10^0))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


long power_10 (int exp)
{
    long res = 1;
    int  i;  

    for (i = 1; i <= exp; i++) {
        res = res * 10; 
    }   
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int   arr[] = {2, 6, 9}; 
    int   i = 0;
    int   len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    long  num = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        num += arr[i] * power_10((len - 1 - i));    
    }   
    printf("%ld\n", num);
}
```

Comment: no, [`pow` is absolutely the wrong tool to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057687/why-the-result-of-pow10-2-99-instead-of-100), would downvote this answer twice if I could

Comment: @AnttiHaapala With my own version to get powers of 10, this should not be a problem. I have modified the answer. I guess the downvote is no longer needed