# I wrote this C++ code for Palindrome numbers but the power function is giving me one less value in the output than expected

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int n, val, i,sum(0),temp,m(0);
    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin>>n;
    temp=n;
    while(n>0){
        n/=10;
        m++;
    }
    n=temp;
    while(n>0){
        m--;
        i=n%10;
        val= i*pow(10,m);
        cout<<"Power: "<<val<<endl;
        sum=sum+val;
        n/=10;
    }
    if(temp==sum){
        cout<<"Palindrome";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not Palindrome";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here in this part:

```
        val= i*pow(10,m);
        cout<<"Power: "<<val<<endl;
```

If m=2 and i=1 then this should give 100 but I'm getting 99 as output.
This is happening only for the first val and for the other it shows the perfect value

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `pow` operates on floating-point types, and as a result are imprecise -- especially when truncating to integers.  If you want to raise 10 to a power as an integer, just write your own function to do it.  Alternatively, rearrange your math so that each time around the loop you _multiply_ the sum by 10 before adding a value, and you'll get the power function for free.

Comment: `pow(10, m)` use floating point (see [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)).

Comment: You might even get rid of power computation with something like `sum = 10 * sum + i;`

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Don't use integer arithmetic to check number are palindromes.  Numbers are just strings (of digits); read them as a `std::string` and then check to see if the string of characters is a palindrome or not.

Comment: [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why the result of pow(10,2) 99 instead of 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54057687/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714)

Answer (score 1):

`pow` is a floating point function that if poorly implemented by the C++ standard library, can fail to return the best possible `double` even with an integral exponent. You might have better luck with one of the `std::pow` overloads but even then you're at the mercy of the quality of the C++ standard library.

Fortunately though you don't need `pow` at all!

In your first loop, where you set the starting value for `m`, do the same thing with `val`: setting it first to `1` then using `val *= 10;` in the loop body.

Then in the second loop apply `val /= 10` as appropriate.

Take care not to overflow `int`: it can have a range as small as -32767 to +32767 (C++20 widens the lower limit to -32768). It might be an idea to use a `long` or a `long long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side not and unrelated to your "power" problem.

You can read the number as a string. Then you can compare this string with its reversed version. If equal, then you have a Palindrome else not. The standard approach is to use reverse iterators for that.

In the end, you will have only 3 statements in main. And it is not complicated . . .

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    if (std::string number{}; std::cin >> number)
        std::cout << (number == std::string(number.rbegin(), number.rend()) ? "Palindrome" : "No palindrom") << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a good approach here, especially given that the overall program performance is I/O bound. Have an upvote!