# c power function show wrong result

Tags: c++, pow

[Here is the problem result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKyUh.png)

**There result is 3024 but right result will be 3025;
what is the problem please help ! thanks for advance.**

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy the code and output text and paste here in proper format

Comment: duplicates: [Why the result of pow(10,2) 99 instead of 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54057687/995714), [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714)

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Because `pow` is a floating point function that does its job using logarithms.  It converted your 55 to floating point, then did the `pow` function using logarithms.  The result was probably 3024.999999, but when you converted back to an integer, it got truncated.

If you want to square an integer, use `result = result * result;`.  If you must use `pow` for integer numbers, do

```
result = pow(result,2)+0.5;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `std::lround` be preferred?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (ubuntu), the result is 3025.
According to another answers, the problem is about the purpouse of pow implementation, with small calculations can be inaccurate, so, try with

```
result = result*result
```